# PowerApps Progress bar

Tags: powerapps, model-driven, powerapps-modeldriven

I've found "innovation challenge" template in PowerApps. I admit, there is something really interesting in that template. I mean - that bar:

Progress Bar

[image: 1]

Is there any way to create it by myself?

Or I need to install that template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one you are looking for is called Business Process flow,
you can create your own, There is an template for it.
[Take a look at this MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/user/work-with-business-processes)
Here is  [another docs from Ms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/business-process-flows-overview)